# How do I call the WooCommerce variable product dropdown and add to cart to any page?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website in development with a WooCommerce ticket system. There is an event page on the site which lists events and their woocommerce linked ticket. Whenever I call the add to cart short code for a variable product, it displays a "Select options" button. Is there any way for me to directly place the dropdown, quantity and add to cart button directly into the event listing?

Here is the site: [intelectsolutions.im/events](https://intelectsolutions.im/events)

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to modify 'content-product.php'.

Find a line `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );`

And replace that with following codes -

```
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’, ‘woocommerce_template_single_title’, 5 );
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’, ‘woocommerce_template_single_price’, 10 );
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’, ‘woocommerce_template_single_excerpt’, 20 );
do_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’ );
```

For more details check the page where did I got it from - http://www.mingocommerce.com/variable-product-add-to-cart-listing-page/